# Display a play button in share thumbnails wordpress

Tags: plugins, wordpress, thumbnails, social-networking

I want to display a play button in share thumbnails like is picture :[click here to view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uI612.jpg)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

place the thumbnail in a `div` with a class name

```
<div class="play-icon">
<?php the_post_thumbnail();?>
</div>
```

then in your css:

```
.play-icon{
    position:relative;
}
.play-icon:before{
    content: "";
    height: 75px;
    display: block;
    width: 75px;
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 0;
    background-image: url('images/play-icon.png');
}
```

[i made a quick svg image of a play icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7D9KF.png) - you can use your own.
[image: play icon]

Comment: will it work when sharing a media? or just on the website?

Comment: i dont understand your question